# Extra space on the left side of webpage

Tags: html, css

I am working on  a new website.
I have an extra space on the right side of the website that I can not exactly determine were does it come from.

I used CSSEdit and Firebug to inspect the css of the page but it didn't help. All I can say is that when I remove the images slider this gap disappears. but again I can not understand what in this div causes the problem.

What could it be?

[Link to the website](http://shanoga-work.com/?page_id=159)

Comment: Note: No gap on Chrome 24. Can't test with Firefox right now.

Comment: Reproducible with Chromium 22 for me.

Comment: In my chrome its work fine..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the flex-direction-nav (`flexslider.css`:54), you set the following style:

```
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    left: -36px;
}
```

Since the element is at the very left, that makes the site larger. Remove the flexslider, put it farther to the right, or change/delete that (questionable) CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hidden the overflowing content

```
#site {
position: relative;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

It will definietly work